# VBA round(var,1) results in floating point error

Tags: excel, vba, floating-point, rounding, precision

I am using VBA to calculate and print a value to a worksheet.  The calculated value is a "single" and I want to round it to one decimal place.  For some reason, the "round" function rounds to the nearest decimal, but it still has what looks like floating point error on top of it.  I can fix this manually, but I'd rather not have to every time and would like to understand what's actually going on.

I used the following code.

```
mysheet.Cells(row, ctotal).Value = Round(ttime, 1)
```

In one example, ttime is 2.183333 and the value that gets printed in the corresponding cell is 2.20000004768371.  I would like it to print "2.2" in this case, without the rest of the nonsense thereafter.  Any ideas?

Comment: You can control how the value is displayed by setting the cell format.

Comment: `Round` is known to be buggy. This is addressed in my library for precise rounding: [VBA.Round](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Round).

Comment: What you want is to display the string containing the rounded number. What you do is transform number to number, and the result is not exactly representable. So you get the closest representable number in the cell. You can still adjust how the cell transforms the number into a string, as in the answer (but then you would not need to round previously). See "Related" - "Is floating point math broken?".

Comment: @LutzLehmann - I think you didn't mean to use "string" here. `Round` or `WorksheetFunction.Round` obviously don't return a string, nor does `.NumberFormat`  convert the underlying value to a string.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `WorksheetFunction.Round`, since [`Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/round-function) uses bankers rounding.

As a side effect, the return of `WorksheetFunction.Round` is a `Double`:

```
Dim ttime As Single
ttime = 2.183333
    
Debug.Print TypeName(Round(ttime, 1)) ' returns Single
Debug.Print TypeName(WorksheetFunction.Round(ttime, 1)) ' returns Double
```

If you do want bankers rounding, then:

```
Round(CDbl(ttime), 1)
```

You can control the decimals displayed by changing the cell's `.NumberFormat`:

```
mysheet.Cells(row, ctotal).NumberFormat = "0.0"
```